# Diameter or drawing way off when zoom is >13 on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm writing some drawing tools for Google Maps where a user selects a tool and clicks and drags to get a distance. Here's a gif of what the "ruler" tool looks like:

[image]

I made a rectangle one too and that works perfect as well. I'm having issues though with a Circle tool in calculating the diameter or radius of the circle once the zoom level is greater than 13. You can see the distance in the gifs below. The first one is zoom level 13, next is 14.

[image]

[image]

Here's the code I have:

```
  var diameter = drawingManager.distanceBetweenTwoLatLng(
    this._startPosition,
    drawingManager.fromEventToLatLng(event)
  );

  this.circle.setOptions({
    // After level 14 zoom we don't multiply *1000. *1000 is a Magic Number™
    // and I have no idea why I need it or why zoom level 14 needs to not
    // have it but 13 and does.
    radius: map.getZoom() > 13 ? diameter : diameter * 1000
  });
```

I calculate the pixels to LatLng with this (and where I think it might be failing because it gets the scale?):

```
  var map = this.settings.map;
  var projection = map.getProjection();
  var topRight = projection.fromLatLngToPoint(map.getBounds().getNorthEast());
  var bottomLeft = projection.fromLatLngToPoint(map.getBounds().getSouthWest());
  var scale = 1 << map.getZoom();
  return projection.fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(x / scale + bottomLeft.x, y / scale + topRight.y));
```

The problem is the drawingManager methods shown above (`distanceBetweenTwoLatLng` and `fromEventToLatLng`) work totally fine with all the other tools zoomed at any level.

You can see my current workaround is just checking for the zoom level and giving it different radius settings.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Where do the "drawingManager methods shown above (`distanceBetweenTwoLatLng` and `fromEventToLatLng`)" come from?  They are not in the documentation.  What are they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more debugging my coworker pointed out that maybe the distance scale was off. I had assumed (incorrectly) that the distance scale needed to be what google maps is set to. So if the user has it on miles it would be miles, for example. I went to their docs and saw it needed to be in meters. Seems so obvious now :\ Anyway, my issue was that i was using the user's current distance scale rather than `m` which is what Google's Circle shape uses exclusively.